# Calculate mean, median, and mode from list of integers

Tags: error-handling, statistics, rust

I am trying to solve a problem put in [The Rust Programming Language #2](https://rust-lang.github.io/book/second-edition/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary)

> Given a list of integers, use a vector and return the mean (average), median (when sorted, the value in the middle position), and mode (the value that occurs most often; a hash map will be helpful here) of the list.

I decided to put the values in a simple struct and return a `Result`. I want to be sure I'm using all the language features within the calculations and I want to reduce the amount of casts if possible.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

/// structure to represent the values after calculating the mean,
/// median, and mode of some integers.
/// the mode Vec holds each individual mode.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Calculations {
    mean: f64,
    median: f64,
    mode: Vec<i32>,
}

/// calculates the mean, median, and mode of values.
/// returns a Result holding a Calculations or an error string
/// when given an empty slice
pub fn calculate_mmm(values: &[i32]) -> Result<Calculations, &str> {
    // if input is an empty slice, return an error message
    if values.is_empty() { return Err("Found empty slice") }

    // add all numbers together and divide by length
    let mean = values.iter().fold(0, |p, &q| p + q) as f64 / values.len() as f64;

    // sort all values and return middle element or average of middle 2 elements
    let median = {
        let mut sorted = values.to_vec();
        sorted.sort();

        if sorted.len() % 2 == 0 {
            (sorted[sorted.len() / 2] + sorted[(sorted.len() / 2) + 1]) as f64 / 2.0
        } else {
            sorted[(sorted.len() as f64 / 2.0) as usize] as f64
        }
    };

    // holds modes
    let mut mode: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    // holds each number and the number of times it occures
    let mut occurrences = HashMap::new();

    for i in values {
        let count = occurrences.entry(i).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
    }

    // the maximum times a value occurres
    let mut max_value = 0;

    for &value in occurrences.values() {
        if value > max_value {
            max_value = value;
        }
    }

    // find the numbers which occur the maximum number of times
    for (key, value) in occurrences {
        if value == max_value {
            mode.push(*key);
        }
    }

    // return all values
    Ok(
        Calculations { mean: mean as f64, median: median as f64, mode: mode }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There's no `main` method and more importantly, there are no tests. How do you know if the code works?
2. It's probably an artifact of learning a new language, but the code is overly documented. There's no reason to have comments describing what the implementation of the code is. It's more important to describe *why* a given implementation was chosen.
3. I would break out smaller functions to have somewhere for names to hang off of.
4. Documentation aspects:

   1. "returns a ..." in docs is not useful; the return type already says that.
   2. It **is good** to say why an error can occur though. You can also create a named error type that might have a variant like `Error::EmptySlice`, which is more self-describing.
   3. "structure to ..." is docs is not useful; it is a `struct`.
   4. "represent" is all programs do, so is redundant.
   5. Avoid referring to concrete implementation details ("... is a `Vec` ...")
5. You have a good use of `fold`, but `sum` exists.
6. Median **is** the mode of the middle of the sorted vector. Now that there are functions, you can reuse them.
7. Why convert to a floating point, divide, then back to a `usize`? (`sorted.len() as f64 / 2.0) as usize`)
8. Don't declare the type of `mode`; let the compiler's type inference handle it.
9. Use `Iterator::filter` instead of the `if` in the loop.
10. Use `Iterator::map` instead of the manual destructuring in the for loop `for (key, value)`.
11. Use `Iterator::collect` to create the `Vec` instead of creating it and pushing to a `Vec`.
12. I'd oneline the counting with the `HashMap`.
13. Use `Iterator::max` and `unwrap_or` to find the biggest value instead of doing it by hand.
14. You *could* track the maximum value during the first loop. This would save one iteration, but it's not as pretty.
15. The casts to `f64` wen creating the structure are redundant; the values are already `f64`.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

/// The mean, median, and mode of some integers.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Calculations {
    mean: f64,
    median: f64,
    mode: Vec<i32>,
}

fn mean(values: &[i32]) -> f64 {
    let sum: i32 = values.iter().sum();
    sum as f64 / values.len() as f64
}

/// Returns the middle element of the elements in sorted order (or the
/// average of the middle 2 elements)
fn median(values: &[i32]) -> f64 {
    let mut sorted = values.to_vec();
    sorted.sort();

    let mid = sorted.len() / 2;

    if sorted.len() % 2 == 0 {
        mean(&sorted[(mid - 1)..(mid + 1)])
    } else {
        sorted[mid] as f64
    }
}

fn mode(values: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut occurrences = HashMap::new();

    for i in values {
        *occurrences.entry(i).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    let max_value = occurrences.values().cloned().max().unwrap_or(0);

    occurrences.into_iter()
        .filter(|&(_, v)| v == max_value)
        .map(|(&k, _)| k)
        .collect()
}

/// Calculates the mean, median, and mode of values.
/// It is an error to pass an empty slice
pub fn calculate_mmm(values: &[i32]) -> Result<Calculations, &str> {
    if values.is_empty() {
        Err("Found empty slice")
    } else {
        Ok(Calculations {
            mean: mean(values),
            median: median(values),
            mode: mode(values),
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", calculate_mmm(&[3, 2, 1, 2]));
    println!("{:?}", calculate_mmm(&[3, 2, 1]));
}
```

Comment: @BradyDean I'm sure that it passes all the tests provided :-D. What appears to be wrong with it?

Comment: Ah; wretched off-by-one errors. Fixed now, and I simplified the odd case, even though that shouldn't have mattered for correctness.

Comment: I forget that slicing syntax doesn't include the right value so that tripped me up.